# Not able to add a position to my existing LinkedIn profile Experience section

Tags: linkedin

I clicked Profile > Edit Profile, but there is no "Add position" button.

I'm trying to add another job to my Experience section.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? Because it must be at the last in the experience section (after the first job you have added).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're logged in?

When I view my profile, at the top of the "Experience" section...

[image: top of "Experience"]

...if I mouse-over, an "Add position" button pops up.

[image: top of "Experience" with "+ Add position"]

Further, at the bottom of the "Experience" section is an "Add position" link.

[image: "Add position" link]